# Instagram API Review Wait time

Tags: c#, instagram-api

I am using Instagram API graph in my project.

I submitted my app for review and was wondering if anyone maybe knows how long it takes for a pending review to go through?

I have tried reporting a bug with this problem but does not seem to look like i'm coming right, i have also left a comment on the Blog to see if someone can assist me with this but also no answer i don't know if the Instagram people closed for the year but it seems quite difficult to get in contact with them.

ANY pointers that i can try for this will be much appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys i found out that instagram review takes anything from 1 week - about 2 months i sent through 2 apps for submission one was accepted in 3 days and the other one was just over a month hope this helps anyone else that was wondering how long the review takes